# Visa requirements for children born abroad

Tags: uk-visa, uk-citizens, children

just looking for info as I find the Uk gov website confusing regarding visas for children born abroad and I cannot find anything specific relating to my situation.

I am a British Citizen **not by decent** currently residing in the Philippines and me and my wife who is a Filipino national have just had a baby boy.

We are wanting to visit the Uk for a vacation next March 2019 by which time the baby will be six months old.

My wife already has a five year visa so have no problem there, but do I have to apply and wait until I can get a UK passport for my son in order for us to visit the Uk?, or can I get my son a Filipino passport in the interim period and apply for a visa to visit the UK while we are waiting for the processing of the UK passport? Having to wait for the issuance of the Uk passport will probably mean we couldn't visit the UK in March due to the processing times.

Any advice please?

Comment: You mean it will take more than 6 months to get a British passport?

Comment: @user102008 apparently this is not unlikely. The government [says](https://www.passport.service.gov.uk/overseas/information/philippines/first/child/philippines) it will take at least 16 weeks plus time in the post, but there are [additional requirements for establishing the validity of marriages in the Philippines](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/applying-for-a-passport-from-outside-the-uk-applicants-with-links-to-the-philippines/applying-for-a-passport-outside-the-uk) which can require extra time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a British citizen "otherwise than by descent", then any child of yours born abroad is automatically and involuntarily a British citizen at birth. As a British citizen, your son should apply for a British passport to visit the UK. I don't think they will issue a British visa to a British citizen.

Comment: Aren't there some circumstances, such as the parent being abroad in crown service or service of the EU, under which the child could be a British citizen otherwise than by descent?  Your last sentence is correct.  At https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa there is a very prominent message: "Your application will not be accepted and you will not get a refund if you have the right of abode in the UK (for example you’re a British citizen). You need to apply for a certificate of entitlement instead."